# What is the grammatical function of the noun "Accès" in the term "la barre d'outils Accès rapide" in Office Word?

Tags: grammaire

> Personnaliser la barre d'outils **Accès** rapide.

I imported a PC from France, and in Office Word I noticed the term "la barre d'outils Accès rapide" that refers to the customisable bar at the top of the screen. {as highlighted in the attached picture}

The use of the noun "Accès" in this specific manner pulled me up short. I wonder how this is considered grammatically correct? Why is only the word "Accès" capitalised, whereas its English equivalent "Quick Access Toolbar" has every first letter capitalised?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not find anything non grammatical here. Unlike English, French do not capitalize every word in a title or similar.

There is a toolbar (*barre d'outils*) named *Accès rapide* and a menu to customize (*personnaliser*) it.

In English, this function is called "Customize the Quick Access Toolbar".

*Accès* is capitalized to show it starts the proper name of an entity (similar to the title of a book, or the name of a chapter).

To better stick to typographical rules, it might have been quoted too like this:

> Personnaliser la barre d'outils « Accès rapide »

or italicized:

> Personnaliser la barre d'outils *Accès rapide*