# « D'/à/en accès rapide » etc. : comment introduire l'apport du type « quick access » au nom ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage, prépositions, comparaison-de-langues

À la lecture d'une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27179) où l'on se demande pourquoi [on](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/Personnaliser-la-barre-d-outils-Acc%C3%A8s-rapide-43fff1c9-ebc4-4963-bdbd-c2b6b0739e52?ui=fr-FR&rs=fr-FR&ad=FR) adjoint à l'idée de la barre d'outils d'une interface logicielle la notion d' « [accès](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acc%C3%A8s) [rapide](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapide) » avec un marquage particulier, pour des fonctions courantes, je me demandais comment on exprime plus généralement mais de manière descriptive en français cet « apport » du *quick access* au nom qu'on trouve parfois au vocabulaire technique de langue anglaise. Ce qui mène à une réflexion sur la manière d'introduire un tel apport, en particulier avec la *préposition*...

En regardant brièvement différents termes employés pour traiter du *quick access/hot key* par exemple, on réfère à des traductions comme la *touche de raccourci/d'accès rapide* ou l'idée de la *touche directe*. On a aussi des applications plus concrètes comme par exemple le [*quick access (flight) recorder*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=QUICK%20ACCESS%20FLIGHT%20RECORDER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) qu'au lexique de l'aviation civile on désigne sous le vocable d'*enregistreur à accès rapide*, et ailleurs sous celui d'*enregistreur de données de vol d'accès facile*.

> (nom) [d](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)'accès rapide. 
>  (nom) [à](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) accès rapide. 
>  (nom) [en](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)
>   accès rapide. 
>  (nom) rapide/facile d'accès. 
>  (nom) facilement/rapidement accessible.

---

- Quelle préposition, ou tournure croit-on objectivement la plus apte à
  introduire un apport au nom se comparant à celui du *quick access* en vocabulaire technique, et pourquoi ;
  que le nom réfère à un inanimé concret, à sa représentation, ou à une abstraction y change-t-il quelque chose ou peut-on généraliser ?
- Y a-t-il une équivalence sémantique entre la *rapidité* et la *facilité* en apport à l'*accès* et le cas échéant lequel serait le plus usuel ?
- La préposition change-t-elle le sens dans ces exemples, sont-ils tous cohérents, équivalents et acceptés ; y a-t-il un usage consacré qui s'appuie sur l'une de ces prépositions avec l'*accès rapide*, est-ce figé ?
- Que pourrait bien signifier l'apport « en accès rapide » ?

Comment: @Alone-zee You may find this interesting. Thanks!

Comment: FYI ping to someone who didn't left a comment yet doesn't work.

Comment: @Tensibai Merci, je n'étais pas du tout au courant...

Comment: Pour un peu plus de détails au besoin: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications/125212#125212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À mon sens les deux tournures suivantes sont possibles mais ont un sens différent :

- "à accès rapide" indique qu'une chose est conçue pour être rapidement accessible (par exemple un enregistreur)
- "d'accès rapide" indique que la fonction d'une chose (une barre, une touche) est de permettre un accès rapide à d'autres fonctions

Je ne serai pas choqué par l'usage de "en accès rapide", et je comprendrais cette tournure comme indiquant un mode, une manière d'accéder à quelque chose (par exemple si on peut accéder à une fonction de deux façons différentes, on peut obtenir cette fonction "en accès rapide").

La tournure "facile d'accès" s'emploie couramment pour toutes sortes de choses (pour des endroits auxquels on accède facilement en voiture par exemple, mais aussi pour signifier qu'un texte est facile à comprendre). "Accès rapide" me semble plutôt être spécifique à l'informatique, aux raccourcis en particuliers, et être une traduction de "quick access".

Comment: Merci ! Et donc vous vous fiez beaucoup sur la préposition qui introduit et peu sur le mot qui précéderait... je me demande d'une certaine manière quelles nuances des noms précédant pourraient changer le sens ou la valeur de la préposition. Oui, le _mode_ pour _en_, ça rappelle des trucs mécaniques...

Comment: Sans être specialiste de grammaire, ce qui me semble important ici c'est que le nom qui suit "de" et "à" est sans article. Dans ce cas, j'ai l'impression que "de" en vient à indiquer une fonction (comme dans "salle de sport", "bouteille de vin") ou une constitution  ("mur de pierre") et "à" une caractéristique ("chemise à rayures", "chaussures à crampon"). Donc par analogie, "d'accès rapide" indiquerait que la fonction de l'objet est de proposer des accès rapides et "à accès rapide" que c'est une caractéristique de l'objet que d'être rapidement accessible. Mais bon c'est assez intuitif.

Comment: Assez intuitif mais assez bon, merci !